# Reading Esri TIN file directly using QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, tin

Can QGIS open directly a TIN file generated with ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 5):

It is an new feature in the future release QGIS 3.10. 
QGIS can now read ESRI TIN as this format is now supported by the [MDAL library](https://www.mdal.xyz/).

**Edit :** 
Finally, it seems it will available in the future release QGIS 3.12 (end of February 2020).

Answer (score 1):

No, and I don't know of any non-ESRI software that does. Your only solution is to convert the TIN to raster or vector files.

Comment: I'd go a step further and request the original data used to make the TIN.  The method of triangulation in the TIN is not always the best, depending on what you are going to do with it and not necessarily something I'd want to rely heavily on for my analysis if I could get the original data.